# local storage data to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, local-storage

I happen to have a feature on my web app that saves data into local storage, which I then convert into a json object. Is there a way for me to pass the local storage data to my server using ajax. I would like to have other clients of my web app access that data.

Answer (score 1):

You would pass the `localStorage` values through `ajax` as you would any other parameters, like so:

```
 // jQuery ajax call.
 $.ajax({
   url: "test.html?jsonValue=" + localStorage.getItem("foo"),
 });
```

There is no special way of passing `localStorage` values around like there is for `cookies`.